# uwsgi + django : ImportError: no module named OS

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

**================ UPDATE ===================**

I tried to comment out home, pythonpath, virtualenv, and env variables from the ini file, and set the PYTHONPATH in my wsgi.py like this:

```
os.environ.setdefault("PYTHONPATH", "/root/virtual_env")
```

However, I'm getting this new error:

**> ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi**

So trying to address this new problem, I created a .pth file and placed it on the site-packages of my virtual environment (i.e. **/root/virtual_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages**) containing this:

> /root/virtual_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django

But after doing so, the error still remains when I run ../bin/uwsgi myproject_uwsgi.ini

**===================== END OF UPDATE ======================**

Inside my virtual environment (via virtualenv), I am still experiencing an

> ImportError: No module named os
>     unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
>     *** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***

when I run ../bin/uwsgi --ini myproject_uwsgi.ini. Below are the complete contents of the said ini. As you can see below, I already home, pythonpath, virtualenv, and env variables/parameters, to get away with the error. Still, no luck. What should I do here? Thanks in advance!

```
#myproject_uwsgi.ini file
[uwsgi]

# Django-related settings
# the base directory (full path)
chdir           = /root/virtual_env/myproject
# Django wsgi file
module          = myproject.wsgi:application
# the virtualenv (full path)
home            = /root/virtual_env/myproject
pythonpath      = /root/virtual_env/myproject
virtualenv      = /root/virtual_env/myproject
env             = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myproject.settings

# process-related settings
# master
master          = true
# maximum number of worker processes
processes       = 4
# the socket (use the full path to be safe
socket          = /root/virtual_env/myproject/myproject.sock
# ... with appropriate permissions - may be needed
chmod-socket    = 777
chown-socket    = uwsgi:uwsgi
# clear environment on exit
vacuum          = true

# other config options
uid = uwsgi
gid = uwsgi
processes = 4
daemonize = /var/log/uwsgi/myproject.log
no-site = true
```

Comment: Where is your actual virtual environment (is usually not where your source code is).

Comment: its /root/virtual_env

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that there is a problem with your virtualenv.

`pythonpath` and `virtualenv` should not be equal.
Virtualenv should be in your project's directory.
For example, if your project located in /root/myproject, than your virtualenv 
should be in /root/myproject/virtual_env. 
Also your DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is incorrect.

After all your uwsgi.ini should looks like this:

```
#myproject_uwsgi.ini file
[uwsgi]

# Django-related settings
# the base directory (full path)
chdir           = /root/myproject
# Django wsgi file
module          = wsgi:application
# the virtualenv (full path)
home            = /root/myproject
pythonpath      = /root/myproject
virtualenv      = /root/myproject/virtual_env
env             = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings

# process-related settings
# master
master          = true
# maximum number of worker processes
processes       = 4
# the socket (use the full path to be safe
socket          = /root/myproject/myproject.sock
# ... with appropriate permissions - may be needed
chmod-socket    = 777
chown-socket    = uwsgi:uwsgi
# clear environment on exit
vacuum          = true

# other config options
uid = uwsgi
gid = uwsgi
processes = 4
daemonize = /var/log/uwsgi/myproject.log
no-site = true
```

Comment: thanks for your help. Still encountering the same error though

Comment: Did you change locations of your code and virualenv? If you still get the same error, try to start with empty project.  Then create virtualenv inside it and try to run it with uwsgi. You should also install uwsgi as pip package inside your virtualenv.  Try to implement this tutorial: https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html#the-first-wsgi-application.